# AsyncStorage mergeItem - Unrecognised selector

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

Hi I'm trying to do a simple get and update using AsyncStorage in react native.

I get the data in componentDidMount() using the following code:

```
   AsyncStorage.getItem('mytrips', (err, result) => {
      if(result !== null){
        var data = JSON.parse(result);

        console.log(result);
        this.setState({
          email: data.email,
          firstname: data.firstname,
          lastname: data.lastname,
          phone: data.phone,
          mobile: data.mobile,
          phonecode: data.phonecode,
          DOB: moment(data.DOB).format('DD MMM YYYY'),
        });
      }
    });
```

Following some user input I want to update what's in storage using mergeItem.

```
AsyncStorage.mergeItem('mytrips', JSON.stringify(data));
```

data is an object of all the changed values.

I get the following error when mergeItem is called.

```
ExceptionsManager.js:71 Exception '-[__NSArrayI objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000886400' was thrown while invoking multiMerge on target AsyncLocalStorage with params (
        (
                (
            mytrips,
            "[\"Carl\",\"Carl\",\"11111111\",\"111111111\",\"\",\"1900-01-01\",\"carl@test.com\"]"
        )
    ),
    3657
)
```

Any idea what could be causing the selector to be unrecognised? I'm not calling removeItem anywhere in my code.

Comment: Please console the data which you are merging with the 'mytrips'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are merging an array of items as I can see. You can't merge an already stored JSON item with the array of items. As stated in the [react-native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#mergeitem):

> MergeItem: Merges an existing key value with an input value, assuming both values are stringified JSON. Returns a Promise object.

Please try and merge the JSON object with the already saved item to work properly. I hope this solves your problem and if not please let me know :)

Comment: i got null when i log the *mergeItem*, `updateData = () => {
        const { userId, currentUser } = this.state;
        let recentPostsRef = firebase.database().ref(`users/${userId}`);
        recentPostsRef.update({
            username: currentUser.username,
            email: currentUser.email,
            city: currentUser.city,
            mobileNumber: currentUser.mobileNumber,
        }).then(async () => {
            let Data = await AsyncStorage.mergeItem('@MyProfile:data', JSON.stringify(currentUser))
            console.log(Data)
        })
    }`